# In perl, how to connect to remote mongodb?

Tags: perl, mongodb

Set up a db in mongoHQ,

The mongo URI:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@staff.mongohq.com:10022/testdb
```

The mongodb connection as described by the perldoc mongodb:

```
my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'localhost', port => 27017);
my $database   = $connection->foo;
```

If the user is: dbuser
password is: dbpass

What's connection string in perl?

Thanks

Comment: "The mongodb connection as described by the perldoc mongodb"  Seriously? This is more than trivial and would have taken 3 (really 3.. maybe less!) seconds to scroll down in the docs..

Comment: Most questions here have answer in related menu. Some people for some reason can't find the answer. Some one may like to ask someone else for help. That the reason for this site to blooming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [CPAN docs](http://search.cpan.org/~kristina/MongoDB-0.43/lib/MongoDB/Connection.pm),

`host` should be in the format `mongodb://staff.mongohq.com:10022`.

`username` and `password` are the constructor attributes for those fields.

So, for example, you might say

```
my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'mongodb://staff.mongohq.com:10022', username => 'dbuser', password => 'dbpass', db_name => 'testdb');
my $database = $connection->testdb;
```

Comment: Set up as per this example, it works, for the perl file in my computer and the db in mongoHQ. Thank you.

Comment: You must set db_name if you use user/password

Answer (score 1):

```
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $conn = MongoDB::Connection->new(
    host => 'remote server's inet address or host name', 
    port => 27017, 
    username=>'your_user_name', 
    password => 'your_password', 
    db_name => 'your_db_name'
);
```

This code will connect and authenticate you to remote mongodb.

For more details on how to use mongodb with perl check http://search.cpan.org/dist/MongoDB/lib/MongoDB/Tutorial.pod

Comment: Although give no more information than answer 1, this answer give better presentation and promote best practice. So I raise this answer.

Answer (score 0):

for staff.mongohq.com:10022

The host is: staff.mongohq.com
The port is port: 10022

See also, [MongoDB::Connection documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~kristina/MongoDB-0.43/lib/MongoDB/Connection.pm)

Comment: That's why I linked to the documentation

Comment: my $connection = MongoDB::Connection->new(host => 'example.com:12345'); --- The documentation only supply connection to remote host, without supply database, username and password parameters. If look at the mongodb docs, and look inside the code of Connection.pm may find out the answer.